# Ruby: integrate a ruby key/value-hash in an existing JSON string

Tags: arrays, ruby, json, hash

The JSON-String:

```
jsonString = {"string1" => {"test1" => "test2"}}
```

results (with JSON.pretty_generate) in a pretty printed:

```
{
    "string1":
    {
        "test1": "test2"
    }
}
```

But when I try to add all elements of two arrays into this JSON-String

```
keys = [:key0, :key1]
values = [:value0, :value1]

my_hash = Hash[keys.zip values]

jsonString = {"string1" => {"test1" => "test2", my_hash}}
```

I'm always getting a:

**syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
        jsonString = {"string1" => {"test1" => "test2", my_hash}}**

I would have expected a behavior like this:

```
jsonString = {"string1" => {"test1" => "test2", keys[0] => values[0], keys[1] => values[1]}}
```

Output:

```
{
    "string1":
    {
        "test1": "test2",
        "key0": "value0",
        "key1": "value1"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to this using the hash-mechanism?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `jsonString.merge(my_hash)` ?

My understanding is that the variable called `jsonString` is actually a hash, not a json string. If you wanted to convert that hash to a real JSON string, you could import the json module (using `require 'json'`) than call `jsonStrong.to_json`, but once you've converted the hash to a string it's more difficult to had other hashes to it. It's best to add all the hashes together, then convert the result to json.